# Gráfico do banco de dados não aparece matplotlib python

Tags: python, sqlite, matplotlib

Aparece o esboço do gráfico , porém vazio , sem nenhum dado.

```
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


connection = sqlite3.connect('escola.db')
c = connection.cursor()

sql= "SELECT DATE_EXTRACTION, NOTAS FROM ESCOLA where turma_id='T1'"

x = []
y = []

conversor = mdates.strpdate2num('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S') 


def read_data (wordUsed):
    for row in c.execute(sql):
        x.append(conversor(row[1]))
        y.append(row[2])

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg= 'white')
plt.ylim(0,50000)
plt.xlim(2014, 2015)
plt.plot_date(x, y, fmt='b-', label= 'values', linewidth=2)
plt.legend(['values'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Mensagem:

> ```
> 136: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The axisbg attribute was deprecated in version 2.0. Use facecolor instead.
>   warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu código tem alguns potenciais problemas:

1. As variáveis de dados `x` e `y` são somente preenchidas dentro da função `read_data`, que **nunca é chamada**. Por isso os dados estão vazios e o gráfico não mostra nada. Execute a função antes de criar o gráfico!
2. Mesmo que a função fosse chamada, ela manipula variáveis locais e não as variáveis `x` e `y` globais. Declare-os novamente dentro da função como globais, ou então (eu acho melhor) faça a função retornar seus valores.
3. Potencialmente o fato de vc forçar os limites dos eixos x e y pode também causar que nenhum dado seja exibido. Quando acontecer assim, comente as linhas com `plt.xlim` e `plt.ylim` só pra ter certeza.

Já que você não se preocupou em fazer um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que pudesse ser testado (eu não tenho como rodar o seu código, já que não tenho o seu banco de dados e nem sei que dados são esperados), eu preparei um teste que pega as cotações do Yahoo. A origem dos dados é diferente, mas a produção do gráfico é exatamente a mesma. Veja o código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, MonthLocator, DateFormatter

x = []
y = []

def read_data():

    # Apenas para teste
    # -------------------

    date1 = datetime.date(1995, 1, 1)
    date2 = datetime.date(2004, 4, 12)

    quotes = quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl('INTC', date1, date2)
    if len(quotes) == 0:
        raise SystemExit

    global x # CORREÇÃO: Declare x e y como globais!
    global y

    x = [q[0] for q in quotes]
    y = [q[1] for q in quotes]

read_data() # CORREÇÃO: Chame a função!!

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg= 'white')
#plt.ylim(0,50000) # DEPURAÇÃO: Comente para ver se isso também não contribui para o "problema"
#plt.xlim(2014, 2015)
plt.plot_date(x, y, fmt='b-', label= 'values', linewidth=2)
plt.legend(['values'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu chamei a função e agora funciona, mas queria saber o seguinte: sql= "SELECT DATE_EXTRACTION, NOTAS FROM ESCOLA where turma_id='T1' NOTAS=''C1"", não sei qual forma seria correta para selecionar esses dois grupos

Comment: Quando vc diz "grupos" vc quer dizer cláusulas condicionais? Não está claro. Se são duas cláusulas, talvez falte um `and` entre elas. De todas as formas, como essa sua dúvida é uma nova dúvida, diferente, sobre a montagem da cláusula SQL, você deve abrir outra pergunta. É que [este site não é um fórum](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum).

Comment: Outra coisa: se alguma das respostas te ajudou, por favor considere [marcar uma delas como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

A msg de erro é bem clara, a função `axisbg` foi descontinuada na versão 2.0 e foi substituída pela `facecolor`  tente mudar essa linha:

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg= 'white')
```

por essa

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, facecolor= 'white')
```

Comment: Obrigada! Eu modifiquei, mas o erro continuava isso era pq eu coloquei traço entre as datas e era barra , mas obrigada!

Comment: Apesar do ***warning*** precisar mesmo ser considerado, eu acho que o problema não é esse. :)